# PHP semaphore - sysvshm module missing in SystemD

Tags: php, systemd

In an embedded Linux system (using yocto), we are compiling the rootfs as a systemD (not systemV).

As a result of this, some systemV php (PHP 8.2.7) modules are missing:

- sysvmsg
- sysvsem
- sysvshm.

Is there a replacement of these php modules for systemD ?

Thanks.

php -m result:

**SystemV** **SystemD**
[PHP Modules]   [PHP Modules]
bz2     bz2
Core        Core
ctype       ctype
date        date
dom     dom
fileinfo    fileinfo
filter      filter
gettext         gettext
hash        hash
iconv       iconv
json        json
libxml      libxml
mbstring    mbstring
openssl         openssl
pam     pam
pcntl       pcntl
pcre        pcre
PDO     PDO
pdo_sqlite  pdo_sqlite
Phar        Phar
posix       posix
random
Reflection  Reflection
session         session
SimpleXML   SimpleXML
sockets         sockets
SPL     SPL
sqlite3         sqlite3
standard    standard

sysvmsg     *missing*
sysvsem     *missing*
sysvshm         *missing*

tokenizer   tokenizer
xml     xml
xmlreader   xmlreader
xmlwriter   xmlwriter
zlib        zlib

Answer (score 0):

> As a result of this,

No, it's *not* as a result of that.

These PHP modules have nothing to do with your init system, whether it's systemd or not. The 'sysv' in their name **does not** refer to sysvinit – rather, the 'sysv' in *both* "sysvinit" and "sysvshm" refers to UNIX System V, the operating system that happened to introduce both of those facilities.

Eventually the init system of UNIX System V became known as "SysV init" while the IPC system became known as "SysV IPC", but they remain completely unrelated. In fact, SysV init does not even use SysV IPC for anything. (Meaning, you should not be turning off every possible "sysv" option just because you are not using SysV init!)

For these PHP modules to work, SysV IPC support needs to be enabled when compiling your kernel (the `CONFIG_SYSVIPC` option) and when compiling PHP (the `--enable-sysv*` configure options).